# GIT: How to ignore changed project config-files when commiting, and how to avoid merging config files from remote repo into local?

Tags: git, version-control, configuration

I would like to edit some config files locally and when commiting those changes to repository ignore changed config files. Local config files should stay untouched when updating from repository.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this might suit very well, but only when commiting code:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged somefile.xyz
```

it ignores local changes when commiting code on specified file. Not sure will this prevent updating from repository specified file.